# Bad Input Shape Sklearn Error After HashingVectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, keras

I have 204567 words of which 21010 are unique. Each word is associated with a unique tag. In total, there are 46 unique tags.

I have used feature hashing to map the 204567 words using `HashingVectorizer()`. I have one-hot encoded the tags and used `Perceptron()` model for this multi-class classification problem.

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer 
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

vect = HashingVectorizer(decode_error='ignore', n_features=2**15,
                          preprocessor=None)
X = vect.transform(X_train)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.transform(y_train)
target = np_utils.to_categorical(y)

ppn = Perceptron(n_iter=40, eta0=0.1, random_state=0)
ppn.fit(X, target)
```

However, I receive the following error: `ValueError: bad input shape (204567, 46)`

Is there a better way to encode the tags?

P.S. Please, explain the error and a possible solution

Comment: Post here the outputs from `X.shape` and `target.shape`.

Comment: X.shape = (204567, 32768) and y.shape = (204567, 46)

Comment: *y.shape here refers to target.shape

Comment: Is there a specific need to convert one-hot encoded tags back to categorical. Can;t you just use them as it is in the `Perceptron.fit()`?

Comment: @VivekKumar no there isn't a need to change them back. The problem I am encountering happens to be at the perceptron.fit() part

Comment: I will take a look at it soon

Comment: **Perceptron** requires a 1-D array as a target (y). In your case it is 2-D which causes an error.

Comment: @E.Z. thank you. I'll keep that in mind from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my code as follows and now its working:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
from numpy import array   

vec = HashingVectorizer(decode_error = 'ignore', n_features = 2**15)
X = vec.fit_transform(X_train) 

values = array(y_train)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)

encoded = np_utils.to_categorical(integer_encoded)
print(X.shape)
print(encoded.shape)

clf = MLPClassifier(activation = 'logistic', solver = 'adam', 
                    batch_size = 100, learning_rate = 'adaptive', 
                    max_iter = 20, random_state = 1, verbose = True )
clf.fit(X, encoded)
print('Accuracy: %.3f' %clf.score(X, encoded))
```

I changed my model from Perceptron to Multi Layer Perceptron Classifier though I am not completely sure how this is working. Explanations are welcome.
Now I have to approach the same problem using n-gram model and compare the results.

Comment: Hello Batspock. Look, I think this is more a new question than an answer. If you make multiple questions in the same question, is hard to see the main problem. So, please, take this advice. Your first question is solved, now, once you have your first answer, ask a new question telling the new problems (and you can add the link to this question also). Because it is all complicated this way.

Comment: okay, I'll keep that in mind. I am new to the platform so thanks

Comment: no problem, I'm sorry for not being more helpful in your new question

Answer (score 0):

the function `np_utils.to_categorical()` expects an `class vector` as parameter, you gived a shape

See docs:

**to_categorical**

```
to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)
```

Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

E.g. for use with categorical_crossentropy.

**Arguments**

y: class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from 0 to num_classes).
num_classes: total number of classes.
Returns

A binary matrix representation of the input.

so

```
target = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
```

gives you an error type

Comment: thanks for the help but it didn't actually solve the problem. If it is of any help the shape of X and target are of the form X.shape = (204567, 32768) and y.shape = (204567, 46)

Comment: after hashing X  I get X in the form of:                                                                       (0, 29023) -1.0
  (1, 26650) -1.0
  (2, 11239) -1.0
  (3, 75607) -1.0
  (4, 104082) -1.0
  (5, 174171) 1.0
  (6, 219743) 1.0
  (7, 39639) -1.0
  (8, 220654) 1.0
  (10, 110044) -1.0
  (11, 59251) -1.0
  (12, 162682) 1.0
  (13, 98868) -0.57735026919
  (13, 161582) 0.57735026919
  (13, 225715) 0.57735026919
  (14, 24734) -1.0
  (15, 17830) -1.0
  (16, 148980) 1.0
  (17, 196525) 1.0
  (18, 50743) -1.0  and so on. can you please help me to understand what the labels mean

Comment: i chanded my code as follows and its working fine now:

Comment: please have a look at the changes , your insights are welcome